# What is the meaning of the different app engine package?

Tags: google-app-engine, package

I started a project with Google app engine, when I use eclipse to start, it automatically generate 4 package for me. My app package name is 
com.appspot.xxxx

and it auto generate these three for me:

```
com.appspot.xxxx.client 
com.appspot.xxxx.server 
com.appspot.xxxx.shared
```

What does these three package convention means? Thank you.

Comment: I assume you're creating a Java application. Please confirm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to be clear, these packages are being created because you've chosen to create a Web Application that includes GWT code.

GWT compiles the code in your `client` and `shared` packages (by convention) into JavaScript which will run on your user's browser.

The GWT client-side code will communicate to your server, whose code will go in the `server` package. The server-side code can (again, by convention) use code in the `shared` package, so logic like validation can be used in both client and server code.

This is not an artifact of the app being an App Engine app, but rather of it being a GWT app.

Answer (score 0):

When you register the application, it will be hosted at `http://xxxx.appspot.com`. You choose the value for xxxx, e.g. your application's name.

Comment: I know, but I would like to know wt is the client, server, and shared means by convention, is there any special meanings for that?